# Created a dir in my WordPress installation, changed ownership and rights correctly and still says Forbidden Access?

Tags: wordpress

I have WP installed on my web server. I created a folder where I would store some personal files and want to access it via the web browser but if I simply go to domain.com/mydirectory it says forbidden access. However, the files inside I can view without problem.

I changed ownership to www-data and rights to 755 for the entire folder so I wonder why is this?

Comment: Probably this is because the web server (e.g Apache/nginx) run under a different user than your user account. Make sure that the webserver can read the files and write in the directories.

Comment: When you say you can view the files, what do you mean?

Comment: Give us more information and try to be more clearly. The files inside can you see where? What web server software are you using. What configs did you change? Under what user are you running the web server?

Comment: @Aquiblo I am the 'root' user. I don't know how to make sure the webserver can read the files and write in the dirs.

Comment: @Tom-Oliver Heidel If I go to the files directly in my browser, it loads up in the browser. If I specify only the container folder, I get the forbidden access error.